# How to manage the payload contents of push notifications for iPhone in Ejabberd

Tags: ios, push-notification, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-hooks

I have created a chat application in iPhone with Ejabberd 16.03.
If end user mobile app is not running in the foreground/background, an alert is sent each time a message is received via push notification by Ejabberd.
In the payload of this notification i got JID of user.

Now, i want to add one more field into this payload like *Profile_Name*.   But i don't know the following things:
1) which module is use to send the push notifications?
2) How Ejabberd is sending these push notifications?
3) From where Ejabberd is getting the device token and certificate file(.pem)?
4) How can i configure the payload for the notifications?

I have done some R&D but i get nothing special. I have found many modules for push notifications, but i think there is no need of adding these modules. Because i am getting the push notifications well. I just want to customize the payload of these notifications.
Please tell me how can i do this.

Comment: In default ejabberd CS install, you do not have module to support push.

Comment: Thanks Mickael, But i am getting the push notifications for every offline message and i don't know how. I have read that Ejabberd have Push notification capability from this url https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/ . Well i am sending push in some case from web but i am not using this for chat messages.

Comment: Push is on ejabberd SaaS or Business Edition.

Comment: ok. May i know in the ejabberd SaaS or Business Edition, which module is managing these push notifications.